# Yii- sql request with order by condition

Tags: activerecord, yii2

HOw can i create active query request with "a = 0"

```
SELECT * FROM list ORDER BY a = 0, a;

=>

Email::find()->orderBy('a=0', 'a')
```

Answer (score 4):

This should help you:

```
Email::find()->orderBy([new \yii\db\Expression('a=0'), 'a' => SORT_ASC]);
```

Comment: Isn't it Email::find()->orderBy([new \yii\db\Expression('a=0', 'a') => SORT_ASC]);

Comment: No, it is not the same